# Oracle 11 - sqlplus - rollback the whole script on error - how?

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, rollback

How can I make Oracle 11g rollback the whole transaction on any error in included SQL file?

The file contents are:

```
set autocommit off
whenever SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK

insert into a values (1);
insert into a values (2);

drop index PK_NOT_EXIST;

commit;
```

And the file is included into sqlplus session using "@":

```
@error.sql
```

As expected, the sqlplus session terminates and the output is

```
SQL> @error.sql
1 row created.
1 row created.
drop index PK_NOT_EXIST           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01418: specified index does not exist
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

But when I re-launch sqlplus then the table a contains 2 records which means that there was a **commit** and not a rollback on exit of sqlplus.

Can I somehow force sqlplus to:

1. stop processing file on error,
2. and rollback the whole transaction on error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DDL performs a commit before it runs and after so that even if your DDL fails, oracle will have already committed the transaction.

you could work around it with:

```
set autocommit off
whenever SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK


declare
  procedure drop_idx(i varchar2)  
  is
    pragma autonomous_transaction; -- this runs in its own transaction.
  begin
    execute immediate 'drop index ' || i;
  end;
begin
  insert into a values (1);
  insert into a values (2);
  drop_idx('PK_NOT_EXIST');
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with it is that DDLs that succeed will anyway be committed. So I will get it inconsistent any way. It seems that the only way to apply such a script is to do it step by step, stop on error, and after fixing it continue from where it failed.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue and I post back the solution in case anyone hits such a problem.

If I don't put DDL commands in the script then the rollback is performed correctly.

So the script:

```
set autocommit off
whenever SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK

insert into a values (1);
insert into a values (2);

insert into a values ('x');

commit;
```

works.

And if DDL is used then in general Oracle does not provide rollback functionality.

Comment: To confirm, I just tested a case on 12c with some DDL followed by DML. If you execute `ddl_statement; dml_statement_1; dml_statement_2;` and there is an error in dmlstatement_2, then it will commit (of course) `ddl_statement` but rollback `dml_statement_1` *and* `dml_statement_2`. (This turned out to be acceptable for our case.)