# Oracle. How do I implement nested transactions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have several sql files that are executed one after another in a script like this:

```
@script-A.sql;
@script-B.sql;
@script-C.sql;
...
```

every script file does something usefull and looks like this:

```
DECLARE 
...  
BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE SOME-TABLE';  
  -- lots of inserts into SOME_TABLE
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I have to wrap sql files execution in one big transaction. If execution of any sql file is failed than all previous sql file changes should be rollbacked.

How can I do this?

p.s

as @Mat noticed DDL changes (truncate table) can't be rollbacked. I'm free to refactor this line of code if it's required.

Comment: You can't rollback DDL (truncate is DDL), so...

Comment: @Mat will things change if I refactor "truncate" into "delete from" ?

Comment: Yes, delete is DML and you can rollback from it.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as nested transaction in oracle db. So if you execute `commit` in some place of PL\SQL code call stack it affects on single current transaction (except autonomous transaction but that is another story). But if you eliminate all DDL and `commit` entries you can use **savepoints**. Savepoints allow you to rollback a part of current transaction.

Comment: @agent5566 thank you, may you provide code with all required changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should eliminate DDL and commit from your code. Then add **one** commit line after all script execution. And then finally all you need is to set SQL*Plus parameter to rollback your transaction on firts error. So you need to set  `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm

You can see some example of usage here [Oracle 11 - sqlplus - rollback the whole script on error - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769263/oracle-11-sqlplus-rollback-the-whole-script-on-error-how)

Answer (score 1):

> Here the best way which you can use to control the transaction is by
>   keeping the exception handling inside every script so that if any
>   transaction fails the whole changes will be reverted. The only
>   condition here is to keep the COMMIT at the very end so that on
>   successful transaction of the last wil fire COMMIT. Hope below snippet
>   helps.

```
------------------------------Script 1-----------------------------------------


--Simple query to delete from records
DECLARE
  p_err_cd PLS_INTEGER;
  p_err_msg VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
BEGIN
--  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE EMP ';
  INSERT INTO EMP
  SELECT '123', 'AVRJIT', 'DB', 12, SYSDATE, 1200, 123, 10, '123' FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
  p_err_cd := SQLCODE;
  p_err_msg:=SQLERRM;
dbms_output.put_line('Transaction Rollback');
END;
/

---------------------------------Script 2 ----------------------------------
--Simple query to delete from records
DECLARE
  p_err_cd PLS_INTEGER;
  p_err_msg VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
BEGIN
--  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE EMP ';
  INSERT INTO EMP
  SELECT '123A', 'AVRJIT', 'DB', 12, SYSDATE, 1200, 123, 10, '123' FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
  p_err_cd := SQLCODE;
  p_err_msg:=SQLERRM;
dbms_output.put_line('Transaction Rollback');
END;
/
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Since EMP table has EMPNO as NUMBER field so the second script will fail.
While running the main executing file i.e Full_script.sql


set serveroutput on;
@C:\Av_test_script\Stack_overflow\full_script.sql


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. --> Failed as EMPNO column here is of Invalid datatype

Transaction Rollback
```